# Unity - вызов функции каждые несколько миллисекунд независимо от частоты кадров

Tags: c#, unity3d, таймер

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
shotTime -= Time.deltaTime;
if (((int)(shotTime * 100)) % 20 == 0) audio.PlayOneShot(shotSounds[Random.Range(0, shotSounds.Length)]);
}
```

Я попытался реализовать звук выстрела через определенные короткие промежутки по мере выстрела, но `deltaTime` зависит от частоты кадров, что сказывается на проигрывании у меня звуков - когда я нахожусь в области, где кадров меньше, в `shotTime` из-за малой скорости изменения `shotTime` появляются другие значения, не делящиеся на 20 в данном случае, и периодичность звуков нарушается, причем везде по-разному. Скажите, есть ли кроме `Time.deltaTime` другие средства для данной цели, не зависящие от FPS или у меня вообще костыль и это можно по-другому реализовать?

Comment: почитайте про `Coroutines` https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: либо используйте `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Думаю даже с FixedUpdate периодичность будет нарушаться, я слышал что там все вызовы равно к частоте привязаны, просто они происходят не каждый кадр или несколько раз за кадр

Comment: с FixedUpdate все работает намного лучше, но возникла другая проблема, на правую кнопку мыши я создаю объекты, и теперь иногда вместо одного появляются 2

Comment: Любое событие в играх привязано к частоте кадров, `FixedUpdate()` - не панацея. Ошибка в **очень** странной формуле `((int)(shotTime * 100)) % 20`